# Adding image from a database in a ListView

Tags: asp.net

I have an image in my database that I am able to link to using a `GridView`. Now I am trying to do the same thing with a `ListView`.

I know the column that stores the ID that I want to link to, and I know the path of my image as well. I just want to know how I would link it.

My path is `~/assets/Image/?id={0}` and the column from the table is "AlbumID".

I believe it has something to do with making an image tag in the `<ItemTemplate>` and link to the `<%# EVal("AlbumID") %>`, but I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, you're on the right track.  This should do the trick:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID='Image1' runat='server' ImageUrl='~/assets/Image/?id=<%#Eval("AlbumID") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```